# Invalid URL error message for integrating FB Apps into website with user using static IP

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth

I'm living in Vietnam now. As I known and tested, FB is blocked now. Therefore I have to use static IP for facebook (60.254.175.42). Using this method, I can log into Facebook from WEB browser without any problem. But when I use OAuth protocol to integrate FB into my website (ex. allows user use FB account to log into my website), I always receive the message 'The requested URL "/oauth/authorize?client_id=152190004803645&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Ffb&scope=publish_stream,email,user_birthday,user_location", is invalid.
Reference #9.26affe3c.1328519733.956d48'. 
Please advice,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you using full URL and no just part of it before redirecting user, full URL should look like this:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/authorize?client_id=152190004803645&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Ffb&scope=publish_stream,email,user_birthday,user_location
```

Also check that you defined `localhost` as App Domain in your application settings.

Comment: Yes, of course, I have double checked. The below is my App's settings (for dev. stage, I will change to real URL after deploying)
>App ID/API Key
>212073602219682
App Secret
****************
Site URL
http://localhost:8888/fb
Site Domain
localhost
Contact Email
**********@.com
Support Email
**********@.com

Comment: Your error message about invalid URL doesn't really contain URL from that I assume first part of it somehow missing... Does URL I've posted working as expected?

Comment: @zxwind, how do you construct the URL for login?

Comment: This is the URL: <code>https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=152190004803645&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Ffb&scope=publish_stream,email,user_birthday,user_location</code>

Comment: Well, you just using wrong URL. It should start with `http://www.facebook.com/dialog` see [OAuth Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) and [Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).  `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token` is the second part of authentication flow...

Comment: Yeah, you are right, the error occurred on the second part of the flow. The first part has passed OK. @Juicy: Have you ever using static IP of Facebook via [b](host) file? If yes, try to use the provided IP and let me know the result please. I thought the error comes from this reason, but I can't try any other solution, because FB is blocked from my country (sorry).

Comment: Yeah, you are right, the error occurred on the second part of the flow. The first part has passed OK. @Juicy: Have you ever using static IP of Facebook via **host** file? If yes, try to use the provided IP and let me know the result please. I thought the error comes from this reason, but I can't try any other solution, because FB is blocked from my country (sorry). _Sorry for duplication, because of misunderstanding formatting on Stackoverflow_

Comment: @zxwind, actually this `IP` is not owned by Facebook but Akamai. I think it's better for you to use some kind of tunneling (like [sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle)).

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I understand that but using **host** file is more popular in my country. I cannot press my customers to use tunnelling. In addition, tunneling requires to install some product which can makes some user feel not comfortable. Please help me to check if the reason is exactly `using static IP`

Comment: @zxwind, that probably you want use IP in the NetRange for Facebook http://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;q=69.171.229.11?showDetails=true

Comment: I have tried several of IP from this range. But none of them does work (_I cannot log into FB from web browser_). It seems that this range has been blocked from my country